# "You lost your glove" instead of "You dropped your glove"

Tags: word-choice

I see someone walking towards me. His glove falls out of his pocket and he doesn't notice it.

Can I say

a) You lost your glove.

instead of

b) You dropped your glove.

?

Comment: Have you checked, and thought about, the difference between 'lose' and 'drop'?

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought I had heard 'lose' used that way, but I was not sure at all. I know that that usage isn't in the dictionary, but I thought maybe the word was used that way colloquially (at least in some regions). I guess I was mistaken.

Comment: Not necessarily. To me, as a British English speaker, "You've lost your glove" doesn't sound unnatural (meaning 'it has escaped from your possession without you noticing') - though "dropped" would be more usual.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different meanings to the word 'lost'.

In the context of becoming separated from something, 'lost' generally means that you have misplaced something and do not know where it is, for example "*I lost my wallet*".

The other meaning in this context is to *discard*, *shed* or *jettison* something, for example, "*I lost weight*" or "*he lost a lot of blood*". Things 'lost' in this way can be intentional, or the person can at least be aware that they have 'lost' it.

In your example, neither really makes sense - the person isn't aware that they dropped their glove and it isn't intentional; but nor has the item become misplaced because someone has picked it up and given it straight back to them. Most native English speakers would go with 'dropped' in a case like this.

Comment: You could say you 'lost a tooth' in an accident or fight (give up the gin, Mother!), and still be aware of its location. My father has lost a lot of hair from his head, and, although he wishes he had it back, does not go around looking for it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's kind of incidental. You know it came out, you just realise it would be folly to scrabble around looking for it.